# Pasar datos entre dos componentes livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Actualmente tengo un componente que es un modal con un formulario y otro componente que es una tabla o reporte que se debe generar dependiendo de las opciones en el modal.

Esa es la idea principal y es como debería de funcionar, pero no encuentro la forma de como hacerlo debido a mi poca experiencia con este paquete. Me gustaría aclarar cual seria la mejor practica para abrir un componente desde otro y pasarle esa información.

De esta forma trato de hacerlo:

Este es mi metodo en el componente de modal para abrir el componente de tabla y mostrar la informacion segun lo que envia el modal.

```
 public function generalReport(){
        if($this->month == 1){
            $this->titleGeneral = 'Primera Quincena';
        } else {
            $this->titleGeneral = 'Segunda Quincena';
        }

        $this->emit('generalReport', $this->titleGeneral );
        return redirect()->to('/reportes/general');
    }
}
```

Y este es el componente de tabla o reporte.

```
protected $listeners = ['createPage' => 'generalReport'];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.client.reports.payroll.general-report')
        ->extends('layouts.app')
        ->section('content');
    }

    public function generalReport($title){
        dd($title);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

para pasar datos entre componentes debes considerar los siguiente:

Componente anidado:
Pasas la data a través de la plantilla Blade

```
 <div>

    @livewire('livewire.client.reports.payroll.general-report', ['user' => $user])

</div>
```

La documentacion es https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/nesting-components

La variable puedes disponibilizarla desde el componente con

```
public $user;
```

o pasarla desde el metodo render.

Si esa información la guardas en base de datos, puedes montar el modelo en la tabla, y enviar un evento del tipo

```
'$refresh'
```

Para que la tabla cargue la info enviada desde el modal.